# Erasing text drawn thorugh ExtTextOut function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a class derived from CStatic and on that i m painting lines to show measurement in MFC C++ project. The problem is that I m displaying the line's distance at round about the mid of the line. I m using ExtTextOut function to draw the text. As i m using device context for that, I googled alot to erase that text and redraw on some other location, but i m unable to do. Basically CStatic has an image display over which i m drawing for measurement. Please can anyone tell me how to erase the text drawn through ExtTextOut without harming the background image?

Thanks In advance

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood everything. Show us some code. You also can try the SetBkMode(OPAQUE) function.

Comment: Show the code. in owner drawn controls, basically we redraw everything in OnDraw/OnPaint/OnBgErase functions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just erase the text, leaving what's behind it untouched. You have to redraw the background again.

If you don't want to redraw everything, you can invalidate the part where the text lies (with InvalidateRect or InvalidateRgn) and only that will be redrawn.

Another option, that works with lines but I don't know if it works with text, would be to set the drawing mode with [CDC::SetROP2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/99ax95h9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to R2_XORPEN (I think), draw the text, then draw it again to erase it. By doing it this way, the text will look "mixed" with the background, though.